# CSS: prevent div Y-axis from moving, when I add text inside <p> which is inside that div

Tags: html, css

Look at the div#1, why it goes down when I add some text inside div#2>p
I've been trying to figure out, but nothing. I'm new in CSS.  I cannot understand how it works this css3, I'm not a designer I'm a programmer, it gives a lot of headaches.

p.n: there's no div#1/2 inside the code, both are from the same class: container, Danke

```css
.img {
  width: 170px;
  height:150px;
  background: orange;
}
.contenedor:not(:first-child) {
  margin: 0 50px;
}
.contenedor {
  display: inline-block;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  transition: .1s;
  cursor: pointer;
  resize: none;
  max-width: 170px;
}
.contenedor:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
.leyenda {padding:0 10px 20px 10px;}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>

</style>
<body>
    <div class="contenedor">
        <div class="img">DIV #1</div>
        <div class="leyenda">
            <h4><b>John Doe</b></h4>
            <p><b>This should be up.</b></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="contenedor">
        <div class="img">DIV #2</div>
        <div class="leyenda">
            <h4><b>Jane Doe</b></h4>
            <p>Post you charge here.Post you 
              charge here.Post you charge here.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top;` to `.contenedor` (it has `display: inline-block;`, so it's aligned along the baseline by default):

```css
.img {
  width: 170px;
  height:150px;
  background: orange;
}
.contenedor:not(:first-child) {
  margin: 0 50px;
}
.contenedor {
  display: inline-block;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  transition: .1s;
  cursor: pointer;
  resize: none;
  max-width: 170px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.contenedor:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
.leyenda {padding:0 10px 20px 10px;}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>

</style>
<body>
 <div class="contenedor">
  <div class="img">DIV #1</div>
  <div class="leyenda">
   <h4><b>John Doe</b></h4>
   <p><b>This should be up.</b></p>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="contenedor">
  <div class="img">DIV #2</div>
  <div class="leyenda">
   <h4><b>Jane Doe</b></h4>
   <p>Post you charge here.Post you 
              charge here.Post you charge here.</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 
</body>
</html>
```